# Display hidden div using JavaScript - Works in JSFiddle but not on live site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This code works fine in JSFiddle but I can't get it to work on a live site. I've checked the JS file loads using web developer and all seems fine. I read in one post about loading jquery but I don't know how or if this is needed. Hope someone can help - thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.picassosparadise.com/templates/rt_cygnet/js/2step_2.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="http://www.picassosparadise.com/templates/rt_cygnet/css/reg-form2.css"/>

<div style="margin:0px auto;">
<h2>Sign up for FREE and begin meeting new friends today</h2>
<!-- Make sure you update the URL -->
<form id="lbform" class="formlayout" action="http://app2.picassosparadise.com" method="post">
    <fieldset>

        <div id="mydiv1">
            <div id="mydiv-container1">
                <div id="mydiv-content1">
                    <div class="magic">
                        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="sexuality">
                    </div>

                    <div class="row cf">
                        <label>I'm a:</label>
                        <select class="gender" name="gender">
                            <option>Please select</option>
                            <option value="1">man looking for a woman</option>
                            <option value="2">woman looking for a man</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row cf">
                        <label>First name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="text blur" name="firstname">
                    </div>

                    <div class="row cf">
                        <label>D.O.B.:</label>
                        <select class="day" name="dobday">
                            <option value="">Day</option>
                            <option value="1">01</option>
                            <option value="2">02</option>
                            <option value="3">03</option>
                            <option value="4">04</option>
                            <option value="5">05</option>
                        </select>

                        <select class="month" name="dobmonth">
                            <option value="">Month</option>
                            <option value="1">January</option>
                            <option value="2">February</option>
                        </select>

                        <select class="year" name="dobyear">
                            <option value="">Year</option>
                            <option value="1993">1995</option>
                            <option value="1993">1994</option>
                            <option value="1993">1993</option>
                            <option value="1992">1992</option>
                            <option value="1991">1991</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <a href="#" onclick="show('mydiv2')">CONTINUE</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


                    <div id="mydiv2" style="display:none">
            <div id="mydiv-container2">
                <div id="mydiv-content2">
                    <div class="row cf">
                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="text blur" name="email" id="email">
                    </div>

                    <div class="row cf">
                        <label for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row cf">
                        <button type="submit">JOIN FREE</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row cf">
                        <p class="note">By clicking 'Join Free' you are agreeing to our <a title="Terms of use" href="/help/terms.cfm">Terms of Use</a>.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: if your script is not pure javascript put this in the head before your script file --- <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: The live site is a Joomla site. Can I put the script you mention right in the same module as the rest of the code?

Comment: The script i'm using is:       function show(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
}

function hide(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
}

Comment: You cant typically do a POST to a outside domain using JS. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Rob, that's not the bit that isn't working. It the show/hide div function which I'm struggling with.

Comment: The function you have is pure javascript. Open up the browsers console, do you see an error regarding not finding the function??

Answer (score 0):

Add your functions inside `document.ready` function like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function show(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
}

function hide(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
}
});
```

Also load the jquery library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried those last 2 edits but still not working. Playing around with the toggle function on W3S Tryit Editor as an alternative way of doing what I'm trying to achieve and I can get code to work there but not on JSFiddle!

Comment: Fundamentally, it's not running the script. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not running which script?